# I am looking for a version of the Injil

Tags: scripture

I have been doing some Googling for the Injil but I seem to be finding Christian websites that are trying to evangelise instead. Is there a version of the Injil out on the web that Muslims would read, rather than a rebranded new testament or is the new testament what Muslims would read?

I have read this question:
 [How does Islam view the Christian New Testament?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/how-does-islam-view-the-christian-new-testament)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the question. You are looking for a specific version of the bible? Have you looked at bibles sold in Arabic countries? I'm not aware of a particular version that muslims read.

Comment: Ok I thought that Muslims had a version that they consider uncorrupted.

Comment: @Monkieboy - No. Muslims believe that the uncorrupted Injil had been lost long before Mohammad was sent.

Comment: Muslims tend to view some so called "apocryphal" gospels as more authentic than the mainstream ones. I have read the Gospel of Barnabas which is quite popular in this aspect. see http://www.barnabas.net/chapter_index.htm

Comment: Considering [Islam seems to view the Gospel of Barnabas as illegitimate](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1458/75) as Christianity sees it, I don't see how this makes any sense. Are you implying you see a book that is officially rejected as not authentic ... whatever you're trying to say this needs some references and proper explanation.

Comment: The question asks simply that if there is any version of Bible that Muslims would read and Gospel of Barnabas is one such that Muslims may read due to its contents. It is true that officially Islam does not accept any version of Bible as error free or totally authentic  but since Gospel of Barnabas agrees with Islamic view of Jesus (PBUH) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_of_barnabas#Jesus_not_God_or_Son_of_God                                      it is quite popular in the Muslim world

Answer (score -3, accepted):

During a debate with a Christian Scholar Imam Reza --peace be upon him-- asked the scholar if he knew for how many days Injil was lost after Jesus the Christ --peace be upon him-- and what is the reason behind the Christians going to church every sunday? The scholar answered maybe for a few days, as the answer to the first question, but had no answer for the second one. Then Imam explained that the Injil was lost after the Jesus's ascent, then two of the Christ's apostles said Injil is in our hearth and we will tell it to you, so come to the church every Sunday for us to inform you of its context, then they became 4 and people were going to church to learn about Injil, so that there are 4 gospels each having some differences compared to the three others. But anyway neither is the true one among them, nor are they intact, but all are corrupted. Shia Muslims believe the true one will be brought back to us with Imam Mahdi and Jesus --peace be upon them-- at the end (of the first part) of history! But among the gospels now available the one that goes well with the Islamic teachings is the Barnaba's Injil. According to Grand Ayatullah Bahjat, only four parts in this Injil contradicts with the Islamic Teachings! I have read parts of it. The main points of distinction between this and those most famous gospels are perhaps: Jesus is neither God nor His son but a distinguished creature of God, a prophet, and he repeatedly give glad tidings that a prophet would come after me who is known as Farghteliya (in Arabic it would be: Ahmad), which is the heavenly name of the holy prophet Muhammad, peace be upon him.

PS. I preferred to put this paragraph as a comment to the original question or to the answer given by @windmaker, but I am afraid my writings barely fit the size of a comment.

Comment: I have taken a look at the Gospel of Barnabas but it seems to be contradictory to both Christianity and Islam but I do see why it would be more favoured by Muslims because it does not claim that Jesus was son of God. Some of the draw backs of this Gospel I can see are the fact it was written much later than the other Gospels (by at least 200 years) and seems to have some parts changed too much, for example, the words used in some of the verses translate to 'Admirable One' which has been replaced with the name Muhammad (pbuh) due to it being

Comment: interpreted that way, although the translation does not actually say his name explicitly. I have been reading from the infallible knowledge that is wikipedia :) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_of_Barnabas

Comment: Not claiming Jesus --peace be upon him-- being God or His son is perhaps the biggest contradiction between Islam and the present Christianity. Also if my memory could help the Gospel of Barnabas is claimed to be written by Barnabas, the apostle, not 200 years after the Christ, although there is a debate if any such old version of it exists, many claims this Gospel to be written even after Islam, inspired by Islamic teachings! Anyway, you are right that it also contradicts with Islam in some points, but they are not as fundamental as incarnation and a god in flesh. Godspeed.

Comment: Also I don't think if it will be reasonable for any Muslim to discuss things with Christians based on this Gospel, not approved by any Christian, but it may be interesting for Christians themselves to study Christianity in the Islam's perspective, at least to some extent.

Comment: Totally agree @owari

Comment: The answer to this question (that there is no such thing as a Muslim version available) is buried in this answer, but it is almost impossible to make out for the irrelevant information, poor wording and lack of proper formatting. Please re-write this to address the original question and properly answer that, don't worry so much about what somebody elses answer is. this isn't useful to somebody coming along looking for an answer to the original question.

Answer (score -1):

The Injil is the 4 Gospels. Read without study tools or a trinitarian presuposition and you will see their is nothing wrong with it. As the Quran says "in it is Guidance and Light."

**Quran 5:46**
And We sent, following in their footsteps, Jesus, the son of Mary, confirming that which came before him in the Torah; and We gave him the **Gospel, in which was guidance and light** and confirming that which preceded it of the Torah as guidance and instruction for the righteous.

And let the People of the Gospel **judge by what Allah has revealed therein**. And whoever does not judge by what Allah has revealed - then it is those who are the defiantly disobedient.

Comment: Please add citations.  This is not like a regular internet forum, actually this is not a forum at all.  we require answers to contain proper citations from the Quran, Sunnah, reliable/authentic Fatwas, or from any other Islamic resource.  If you haven't already, we suggest you read the [FAQ](http://islam.stackexchange.com/faq). thank you :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with the new testament?  Really?  Do you really think God would write a book from the views of John, matthew, luke and the like?

Comment: The 4 Gospels are the accounts of human beings. The Gospels are not the Injil.